# Formatação Cint em ASP Clássico

Tags: aplicação-web, asp, vbscript

Boa Tarde...
Gente, estou com uma dúvida em formatação...

na minha tabela, tenho uma coluna com dados nchar(4) (antes era nvarchar(4), mas deu na mesma), no formulário os usuários escolhem em um select para poder preencher e enviar para a tabela.

neste select, eu tenho por exemplo os dados "250", "1166", "2130" 
quando eu faço um relatório na minha pag web (em asc), e peço para ordenar, de forma ascendente, pelos dados desta coluna.. o 250 fica depois do 1166, como se fosse "2500", mas na verdade ele deve aparecer antes, pois o 250 deve ser considerado como "0250".

coloquei, no meu arquivo ASC, para formatar como formatnumber(Cint(dados),"0000")

mas não adiantou.

alguém sabe como corrigir?

obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando uma sintaxe inválida para a função [formatnumber](https://www.w3schools.com/ASP/func_formatnumber.asp).

O que voce tem que fazer é adicionar uma função PAD assim:

```
Function PadDigits(val, digits)
  PadDigits = Right(String(digits,"0") & val, digits)
End Function
```

Depois é só usar desta forma:

```
PadDigits(dados,4)
```

Answer (score -2):

Vc precisa definir com INT e não nchar(4)

Quando colocar o order by Seu_Valor asc vai funcionar